# How can I implement a UIDatepicker with just one component showing each day?

Tags: iphone, ios, date, datepicker, components

A client would like to have a UIDatePicker where only one component is selectable. So in stead of having a seperate day/month and year option the client only wants the option to select a complete date (i.e. 05-03-2013)

Do I need to build a custom pickerview for this which has it's datasource from a nsdateformatter or could I use the native UIDatePicker and only show 1 component?

EDIT:

After some research I ended up with the following implementation. Where I first set up a start and enddate. Afterwords I'm iterating through all the days between the start and enddate and save them inside a mutable array.

```
int numberOfDaysToThePast = 356;
    NSDate * startDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDate * endDate = [NSDate date];
    startDate = [startDate addTimeInterval:-(24 * 60 * 60* numberOfDaysToThePast)];

    dateArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSDate *date = [startDate copy]; [date compare: endDate] < 0;
        date = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:24 * 60 * 60] ) {
        NSString* dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
       [dateArray addObject:dateString];

    }

//add custom picker
    pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200)];
    pickerView.delegate = self;
    pickerView.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:pickerView];
```

Comment: thats not a good one to ask like that..... 100% apps should be like "having a seperate day/month and year option" if u try to satisfy client requirement....then it will be a BIG headache to u...

Comment: You're absolutely right, however as a business we want to satisfy each customer with there own needs. So bring the pain ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a little code snippet but its for a year view you can do some little changes and it would oke

**Objective-C code to create an array of all years since 1960. Perfect for input into a UIPicker**

```
//Get Current Year into i2
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]autorelease];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];
int i2  = [[formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]] intValue];


//Create Years Array from 1960 to This year
years = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i=1960; i<=i2; i++) {
[years addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
}
```

The UIPickerView Delegate Responses

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView: (UIPickerView*)thePickerView {
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
return [years count];
}
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView
titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
return [years objectAtIndex:row];
```

Dont forget the declaration in the interface

```
//Data
NSMutableArray *years;
```

I hope i could help you if not let me know where the problem is good luck and HF